# Hacer funcionar FirebaseLoginViewController con Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, firebase

Despues del anuncio de que parse Cierra en enero del proximo año. He decidido usar Firebase. La buena es que mi App aun esta en desarrollo y no habia avanzado mucho, sin embargo una de las partes que ya habia quedado probada era la autenticacion. Use en su momento PFLogInViewController para facilitarme la vida pero ahora con firebase estoy intentando usar FirebaseLoginViewController que trabaja de forma muy similar, ambas clases (FirebaseLoginViewController y PFLogInViewController ) heredan de UIViewController y al menos en parse fue muy facil personalizarlo. En firebase no hay mucha documentacion al respecto y me estoy dando de topes.

Esto es lo que tengo al momento.

```
import UIKit
class AccesoPrincipal : FirebaseLoginViewController{



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firebaseRef = Firebase(url: "https://superaapp.firebaseio.com/")

    self.loginViewController = FirebaseLoginViewController(ref: firebaseRef)
    self.loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Facebook)
    //self.loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Google)
    //self.loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Twitter)
    self.loginViewController.enableProvider(FAuthProvider.Password)
    // Scenario 1: Set up captive portal login flow
    self.loginViewController.didDismissWithBlock { (user: FAuthData, error: NSError) -> Void in
        if (user) {
            // Handle user case
        } else if (error) {
            // Handle error case
        } else {
            // Handle cancel case
        }
    }



// Scenario 1: Application launches login flow, handles dismissal and routing in `didDismissWithBlock:`
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if (!self.loginViewController.currentUser()) {
        self.presentViewController(self.loginViewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}



override func logout() {
    if (self.loginViewController.currentUser()) {
        self.loginViewController.logout()
    }
}
```

}

El fragmento de código anterior lo he tomado de la propia documentación de FirebaseUi-IOS [https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS] y me he estado dando de topes con los errores.

[image: Errores]

Mi archivo pod install

```
   platform :ios, '9.2'

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 0.3'
```

mi archivo header.h, de donde desconozco si estoy invocando correctamente a FirebaseLoginViewController

```
    #ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h


#endif /* Header_h */
#import <FirebaseLoginViewController.h>
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo a priori es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto debería de ser:

```
var loginViewController: FirebaseLoginViewController?
```

Ya que tal como lo has puesto tú, después de los `:` debe ir el tipo.

Comment: Gracias mhergon, si error mio. fijate que habia declarado esa variable dentro del viewdidLoad al principio y me marco mas errores, luego lo declare despues de la clase, justo como aparece en la imagen pero no lo termine de declarar. Gracias por la aclaración. De momento el error se ha solucionado.